# Not Able To Figure Out Reson for Activity Crash on MI TAB2

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an android application in which I have 2 Activities. When I am running this application on devices it runs perfectly but when I am running it on MI TAB-2, when on activity-2, after a specific time it crashes automatically and restarts from activity-1. It does not crash at same instant, just anywhere in application. It is not giving any error or warning on LogCat. I am not understanding what's the exact issue it is having. Is there any way using which I can figure out the error?

**P.S.** In this device, Google Play Store also crashes in same behavior.

Edit:

`08-11 16:15:41.237 20815-20815/com.example.application I/System.out: qrobj[fieldsData[i]Anuja Ajay Kothekar
08-11 16:15:41.237 20815-20815/com.example.application I/System.out: date26-04-1994
08-11 16:15:48.993 26769-26769/com.example.application I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
08-11 16:15:49.074 26769-26769/com.example.application I/System.out: in onCreate RegActivity
08-11 16:15:49.099 26769-26784/com.example.application I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3595(626KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(67KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 3MB/5MB, paused 12.459ms total 32.716ms
08-11 16:15:49.221 26769-26804/com.example.application D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-11 16:15:49.230 26769-26769/com.example.application D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
08-11 16:15:49.279 26769-26804/com.example.application D/ufoEGL: ENV OGL (32bit) enabled for all processes, use "setptop persist.intel.ogl.procname" to limit it to a single process
08-11 16:15:49.288 26769-26804/com.example.application I/ufoGralloc: Hello, this is UFO GRALLOC/Intel Corporation
08-11 16:15:49.291 26769-26804/com.example.application I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-11 16:15:49.291 26769-26804/com.example.application W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-11 16:15:49.291 26769-26804/com.example.application D/ufoEGL: droid_create_context : config id = 9 conf->NativeVisualID=1
08-11 16:15:49.291 26769-26804/com.example.application I/ufoEGL: Requested context : GLES 2.0
08-11 16:15:49.291 26769-26804/com.example.application D/ufoEGL: Pixel Format : GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
08-11 16:15:49.297 26769-26804/com.example.application D/ufoEGL: Pixel Format : GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
08-11 16:15:49.299 26769-26804/com.example.application D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
08-11 16:15:49.299 26769-26804/com.example.application D/ufoEGL: Pixel Format : GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
08-11 16:15:49.301 26769-26804/com.example.application D/skuwa: Detected device 22B0:32 family 17:11
08-11 16:27:49.825 26769-26804/com.example.application D/ufoEGL: Surface destroy: ANDROID_NATIVE_WINDOW_MAGIC
08-11 16:27:49.846 26769-26769/com.example.application W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection`

This is what I am getting in LogCat

Comment: if the app crashes then the log must contain some information about it. Please post it

Comment: @Lino posted log I am getting when app is crashing.

Comment: from logs it is due unsuccessful firebase initialisation

Comment: I am not using firebase in my project

Comment: Don't filter the logcat, you are probably missing something important.

Comment: No filter is applied. log level is at verbose

Comment: Do you receive some message ? Are you sure is a crash?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a crash. But it is just closing that application after some time and showing launcher window. I don't receive any message.

Comment: Check your code or post it here. Is possibile in your activity2 there is a finish on onCreate? How you call activity2 from activity1?